# Converting IP Address input by using inet_ntop() & inet_pton() (C PROGRAMMING)

Tags: c, sockets, inet

i'm trying to convert an IP address that's inputted by a user so that I can perform some bitwise operations on it and a address already stored in a structure. My problem is however that when the IP address is converted back the output is always 255.255.255.255. For example a input of 10.0.0.1 or 192.16.2.1 always returns 255.255.255.255.

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS

```
  {
        struct sockaddr_in sa;
        char ipinput[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

        fputs("Enter an IP Address: ", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(ipinput, sizeof ipinput, stdin);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, ipinput, &(sa.sin_addr));
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), ipinput, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("IP Address = \%s\ \n", ipinput);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not checking the value returned by `inet_pton`, you would have noticed it fails. As it turns out, it doesn't like the newline left in by `fgets`. Trim it:

```
ipinput[strlen(ipinput) - 1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this:

`inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *)hent->h_addr_list[0],servIP,16);`

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, hostIP, &(sa->sin_addr));
```